# Stack Overflow posts dump: time stamps of views and score changes

Tags: support

I'm a scientist and I've downloaded the dumps of Stack Overflow from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange. The file stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z contains the current view counts and scores of posts. Is it possible to download -- or can the Admins export from the DB -- the time stamps of all views and the time stamps of the score changes? A few colleagues and I are interested in how this system evolves, and we'd like to compare it to other systems.

[*Cross posted to Meta StackExchange*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233834/146015)

Comment: See also *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)*.

Answer (score 3):

Through the Data Explorer, I think the votes data is already available. There is a `Votes` table which has if it was an upvote (`VoteTypeId = 2`) or a downvote (`VoteTypeId = 3`). Then the `CreationDate` column is when that vote was applied. In theory, that data should be available via the data dump on archive.org.

As for views, there's [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter) [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question) over on MSE about how view counts are generated and stored. It seems to be accepted that the time/date/who information of views is not stored, or easily accessible and only the integer of views is stored long term.

Answer (score 0):

For an academic/scientific collaboration, I am pretty sure you can Contact the site admins directly, they will feel less "scrutinized" while agreeing the form and nature of the data they can/will share with your workgroup.

https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Good luck :)

Comment: Please, If you are willing to vote negative my answer, at least provide a comment to improve it. Two votes in 15 seconds and no comment :/ Not very fair...

Comment: Your answer was downvoted because you answered a question that was ***clearly*** off-topic. It has now been migrated to an appropriate site, and your vote count has been reset.